# ArcMap 10.5 Desktop: Highway shield test symbols not respecting mask layer about it

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.5, masking

How do I stop highway symbol markers from appearing above my mask layer?

The actual highway layer is below the mask layer in the drawing order (so the actual highway line appears below the mask layer, but the text symbol still appears above the mask for some reason).
I tried increasing the layer's label weight and increasing the mask's feature weight but neither resolves the issue.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. Please, take the [tour](https://gis.stackexchange.com/tour) and [edit](https://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/270495/edit) your question. Add screenshots showing your problem and explain better the desired output

Comment: is this a label?

Comment: Yes, I it is a label on my highway layer.  It's a text symbol label (to show a highway symbol shield instead of a regular label).  I don't know why the shield is appearing above my mask (even though it's the label for a layer that is below the mask in the drawing order).